# can I name stlyes of Geosever (SLD) in Chinese?

Tags: geoserver, chinese-locale, sld

I have occured a problem when I tried to name styles of Geoserver in Chinese.
I want to know whether Geosever supports styles with Chinese name.

Comment: What version of GeoServer are you using?  Looking at it quickly, I was able to save a style using a Chinese character.